# Make Android 4.0.3 application to support android 3.0 , 3.2, 4.0

Tags: android

I have developed a android 4.0.3 application and I have set the minimum SDK to android 4.0.3. But I need to make my application able to support older version of android platforms ( 3.0, 3.2, 4.0 ). Is there a way to do this.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [API Analysis plugin](http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/) (at the bottom of the linked page), one of the very useful ADT add-ons. Set your minSdkVersion to the lowest level you want to support. The plugin will detect where you are using API calls that are not compatible with that level. You can then either eliminate these from your code or use reflection or other techniques to address the issue. Some useful techniques are described in [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html).